# Attempt to create MySQL temporary table results in error "Base table or view not found"?

Tags: mysql, temp-tables

I'm trying to use a temporary table to hold a bunch of parameters for a search query using the following SQL query:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `patternmatch`
(`pattern` VARCHAR(".strlen($this->fullQuery)."));
INSERT INTO `patternmatch` VALUES ".$insertedValues
```

Where `$this->fullQuery` is a number, and inserted values is a set of data with the format:

`('someData', 'some', 'Data')`

The query itself checks out. Yet, whenever I try and run this query, I get the error:

`SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'photoquilt.patternmatch' doesn't exist`

Any reason for this? How can I fix this? If it helps I'm running MySQL and PHP on XAMPP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can note two reasons:

- Different databases are used in statements (current database names should be the same).
- Different MySQL connections are used (user sessions should be the same).

Check these notes in your PHP code, fix the problem and try again;-)